# rollover text placement in css

Tags: html, css, rollover-effect

[image]So this is some code I have modified to get the rollover text effect. The yellow "block" will be an image so that when it is hovered, some details will pop up. My problem is, when the rollover text appears, the image is on its top left corner. I roll over text's right bottom corner to end up on the image itself.I also need it to pop up only when the block is hovered. I will post an illustration to further explain. here is the code.

```
    [![<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Sweep To Bottom */
.researchers{
  display:none;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:20px;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-bottom {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:before {
  font-size:13px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #333;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover .researchers, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active {
  color: white;
  display:block;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.block{
    background-color:yellow;
    right:80%;
    top:30%;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="block">
<div class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><div class="researchers">Mr.Jones Locker</div></div><div>
</body>
</html>][1]][1]
```

Comment: There's an awful lot of code here for what you're trying to achieve, could you edit this down so we can see the code that is relevant? Also, could you post your HTML?

Comment: As far as I know, all this is need. I would love to see your version of this task. The simpler the better by all means.